Is mantra given by Pasandis valid?
Is mantra given by Pasandis(those who dont follow the veda/people of heretical sects) valid especially if the give Hari naam? What do scriptures say about it?

"bhav kubhav anakh alasu Naam japat magal dishi dashu" Goswami Tulsidas ji says so which means no matter how you chant the holy name it will so your good only.

@S K it is a legit question and there are heretical sects mentioned in scriptures

Yes - instructions related to devotional service (which includes Harinam) which are given by a Pasandi (one who disregards the Vedic injunctions and whose mind is thus polluted by materialistic desires) are said to be a disturbance to the society which implies that they're invalid.

śruti-smṛti-purāṇādi-
pañcarātra-vidhim vinā
aikāntikī harer bhaktir
utpātāyaiva kalpate

Devotional service of the Lord that ignores the authorized Vedic
literatures like the Upaniṣads, Purāṇas and Nārada-pañcarātra is
simply an unnecessary disturbance in society (Quoted by Rupa Goswami in the Bhakti-rasāmṛta-sindhu from the Brahma-yāmala).


avaiṣṇava-mukhodgīrṇam pūtam hari-kathāmṛtam
śravaṇam naiva kartavyam sarpocchiṣṭam yathā payaḥ

One should not hear anything about Kṛṣṇa from a non-Vaiṣṇava. Milk
touched by the lips of a serpent has poisonous effects; similarly,
talks about Kṛṣṇa given by a non-Vaiṣṇava are also poisonous (Quoted by Sanatana Goswami from the Padma Purana).

In the Prameya Ratnavali of Baladeva Vidyabhushana, a Gaudiya Vaishnava author and acarya, he quotes:

First Prameya,
TEXT 5
yad uktam padma-purane sampradya-vihina ye mantras te nishphala matah
atahh kalau bhavishyanti catvarah sampradayinah
shri-brahma-rudra-sanaka vaishnavah kshiti-pavanah catvaras te kalau
bhavya hy utkale purushottamat
The Padma Purana explains: "Unless one is initiated by a bona-fide
spiritual master in the disciplic succession, the mantra he might have
received is without any effect. For this reason four Vaishnava
disciplic successions, inaugurated by Lakshmi-devi, Lord Brahma,
LordShiva, and the four Kumaras, will appear in the holy place of
Jagannatha Puri, and purify the entire earth during the age of Kali."
TEXT 6
ramnujam shrih svi-cakre madhvacriyam caturmukhah shri-vishnu-svaminam
rudro nimbadityam catuhsanah
Lakshmi-devi chose Ramanujacarya to represent her disciplic
succession. In the same way Lord Brahma chose Madhvacarya, Lord Shiva
chose Vishnu Svami, and the four Kumaras chose Nimbarka.

Note: These verse are not extant in the manuscripts of the Padma Purana which are known today, but they have been quoted in some of the books of the Hindu authors from the previous centuries.

No particular sampradaya is being criticized here. There're verses quoted by the Acharyas few centuries ago which may not be available in the versions available online. I can post the references but you don't consider them to be authentic, so how will it help you anyway? Even Advaita Jnana cannot awaken in this manner. Please be mindful of your attempts to tag general Q&As as hate.

Kindly quote more such verses which says harinama from non vaisnavas is not valid

added two more verses..

Add the source (books of Hindu authors if can not be traced to Purana) where these details are provided.
